# What are the 20 SQLEXPRESSnn users for?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I have SQL Server 2016 Express (13.0.4199.0) and my SSMS is 13.0.16106.4

I searched my PC (name Beethoven) user objects and found 20 SQLEXPRESSnn users as follows:

[image]

Who are they and can they be deleted?

I was actually looking for the usual MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS account but it's not there.  Have things changed?